# Subclassing a numpy ndarray is not working properly

Tags: python, numpy

I am just trying to subclass `ndarray` to create a special 2x1 vector with attributes `x` and `y`.

```py
class Vec(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, x:int, y:int):
        # print('In __new__ with class %s' % cls)
        obj = super().__new__(cls, (2,), np.int16,
                              np.asarray((x,y)), offset=0, strides=None, order=None)
        obj.x = x
        obj.y = y
        return obj
    
    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.x = getattr(obj, 'x', None)
        self.y = getattr(obj, 'y', None)

a = Vec(1,2)
b = Vec(3,4)
c = a + b
print(c.x, c.y) # results 1 2
```

what is going wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to override `__new__` instead of `__init__`?

Comment: This is suggested in numpy docs https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `x` and `y` are just another fields of the `Vec` object alongside your 2d array. And numpy doesn't know about them, hence doesn't do anything when calling the `__add__` a.k.a. `+`. So `x` and `y` should be values in the array, and you can make properties out of them:

```
class Vec(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, x:int, y:int):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, (2,), np.int16, np.asarray((x,y)),
                              offset=0, strides=None, order=None)
        obj.x = x
        obj.y = y
        return obj
        
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self[0]
        
    @property
    def y(self):
        return self[1]
        
    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self[0] = x
        
    @y.setter
    def y(self, y):
        self[1] = y


a = Vec(1,2)
b = Vec(3,4)
c = a + b
print(c.x, c.y) # results 4 6
```